# SQL access control error: Insufficient privileges to operate on warehouse

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

After I created a Role and User as Read only for specific tables, The user gets an error: SQL access control error: Insufficient privileges to operate on warehouse
And I can see that the Warehouse is suspended for the Role that I created for him.
What am I forgetting ?

I created with this code:

```
GRANT USAGE ON WAREHOUSE DEV_DWH TO ROLE READ_R_AND_D;
GRANT USAGE ON DATABASE "Z_DWH_DEV" TO ROLE READ_R_AND_D;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA "Z_DWH_DEV"."DWH" TO ROLE READ_R_AND_D;
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE "Z_DWH_DEV"."DWH"."FACT_DAILY" TO ROLE READ_R_AND_D;
grant role READ_R_AND_D to user EYAL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the warehouse set to auto resume? If not, you need further permissions, other than usage to resume it

Comment: If I understand your Question correctly, I want to give access to a specific table and if I will need another one in the future I will grant for it specifically

Comment: Specifies to the privileges are granted on new (i.e. future) database or schema objects of a specified type (e.g. tables or views) rather than existing objects. 

Details: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/grant-privilege.html#optional-parameters

Answer (score 0):

In order for the role to resume the warehouse  - it needs to have to operate on the warehouse.

```
grant operate on warehouse DEV_DWH to role READ_R_AND_D;
```

This grants the role the ability to start, stop, suspend, or resume a virtual warehouse. Grants ability to suspend or resume a task.

Details: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/grant-privilege.html#examples